# How do I make spikes show wherever you would see solidify lines with flipped normals?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, node-editor

Using Cycles, for a cartoony animation character I need spikes to be seen only from the character's edges and behind the character but never seen in facing angles. I want to avoid having to render the scene twice to be composited after.

For example: 2 meshes,
1 skin color, smooth, rigged,
1 blue spiky mesh sticking out, rigged, never seen in front.

I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Do I have to account for camera angle and normals of the spike's base?

Can I just layer one over the other with nodes?

Default look:

[image]

Approximate Desired result done in Photoshop.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to use compositing. I can make an answer when I got time.

Comment: @HenrikD Your confidence is welcomed. I await patiently your solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems like a task for the compositor, but you explicitly stated that you don't want to render multiple times. That means only AOVs remain an option for compositing. After trying it I discarded the idea, because it will cause artifacts. Instead I found a solution using only the shader and some Custom Normals.

First you need to redo the spikes. You need a spike geometry with Custom Normals pointing along the spike direction. You can do that in Editmode of the spike by using *Mesh > Normals > Point to Target* or using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Then you can use instancing to put the spikes at the vertices of your model. Then you need to disable ray visibility for any other ray than a camera ray in the object settings of your spikes.

After this setup you can make this shader:
[image: shader setup with basic toon shader]

The result looks like this:
[image]

You are also free to change your material in any way you want, which could have been difficult with the compositor approach.

Here is the Blend File:
[image]

Comment: Magnificent! Never once did I ever say to myself "ya know what this shader needs? Dot Product!" See this is why I need an expert to get such a thing done. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: How do I not have the spikes pop up at every vertex? Can I use a vertex group to control the layout of the spikes? If so what do I need to to change for that to work?

Comment: OK I figured it out. I just delete the mesh where I don't want it. Well I'm gonna have some fun now using this.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I got was using cones with **inverted normals** and backface culling enabled:

[image: result]

But as you can see, cones pointing slightly towards the camera still get shown.

Comment: That is pretty good, maybe if instead of cones maybe an image plane of a cone?

Comment: This effect only works because of the cone geometry, so an image wouldn't suffice.